# Check 301 Redirect IP

Tags: php, redirect, mpay24

I'm trying to implement a payment processor. All works fine, now i want to check the 301 redirect IP sent by mpay24 when redirecting to the sucessURL.

They described it here:
https://docs.mpay24.com/docs/test-and-productive-system

Problem is how to check the redirect IP? This ofc ain't working:

```
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
        //ip from share internet
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }elseif(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
        //ip pass from proxy
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }else{
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
```

Comment: Are they coming back from another site?  Sounds like you need to check the REFERER?    :O   --- I may be not understanding your question ...

Comment: The Payment site redirects back to the shop site with an URL like:
`"http://www.hotelmuster.com/confirmation.php?OPERATION=CONFIRMATION&TID=9275&STATUS=RESERVED&PRICE=1000&CURRENCY=EUR&P_TYPE=CC&BRAND=VISA&MPAYTID=1682984&USER_FIELD=&ORDERDESC=Example+order&CUSTOMER=9275&CUSTOMER_EMAIL=&LANGUAGE=DE&CUSTOMER_ID=&PROFILE_STATUS=IGNORED&FILTER_STATUS=OK&APPR_CODE=%2Dtest%2D"`

Comment: So is $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] set?